# Inferring reward function and transition model from optimal policy

Tags: reference-request, reinforcement-learning, markov-chains

Consider an MDP where the transition model and the reward function are unknown.

Consider an optimal policy $\pi^*$ generated from this MDP (say by some oracle who *does* know the transition model and reward function).

How can one infer the reward function and transition model from an optimal policy? For such a question, there may be multiple approaches, so this question is mostly a reference request.

Comment: Maybe im just stupid, but can't we assume that \pi^* is deterministic, and for each state put only one transition with reward $1$ to itself for the action $\pi^*$ does, and for everything else reward 0?

Comment: You wont have any way to distinguish between this MDP and any other MDP for which $\pi^*$ is optimal